# Extrapolate & retropolate in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, extrapolation

I have data that shows the price of products once every three years. The pandas dataframe looks something like this:

```
  product_group 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 product
0      x        NaN  NaN  12   NaN  NaN  14   NaN  NaN  shoe
1      x        NaN  NaN  2    NaN  NaN  2.8  NaN  NaN  sock
2      y        14   NaN  NaN  16   NaN  NaN  16   NaN  cheese
...
```

Separately, I also have a dataframe containing the average prices per year for each product group, as a percentage of base year 2015:

```
product_group   2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
0      x        0.84 0.85 0.96 1    0.98 1.02 1.07 1.2
1      y        0.92 0.97 0.99 1    1.48 1.5  1.52 1.75
```

Now I need to find a price estimate for each product, each year by:

- Between two known prices: take the geometric mean of

  1. Extrapolated value from the earlier known value, with the average product group prices
  2. Retropolated value from the later value, with average product group prices

  - So for example here, for the 2015 value of shoe we need the geometric mean of the known 2014 value (= 12), divided by 0.96 and the 2017 value(=14) divided by 1.02
- If only a later price is known: Retropolate from a this known later value (similar to step 2 in the first case)
- If only an earlier price is known: Extrapolate from this known earlier value (similar to step 1 in the first case)

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?